# How to make custom posts that have custom fields in a WP theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-fields

Is there a way to create a custom post (e.g. movies) with custom fields (e.g. title, director, 0 or more actors, etc.) in WP and make it part of a theme? I'm guessing that something needs to be added in `functions.php`, but I'm not sure how to define a custom post type and assign it custom fields.

If this is too hard to do as part of a theme, I'm happy to just create it from the admin section. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `More Fields` Plugin to add custom fields to my posts (Default post type or custom post type).

To create a custom post type (and custom taxonomy of course), I am adding in my `functions.php` a code that works ok and looks like this:

```
        function post_type_aya_bi_aya() {
            $labels = array(
                'name'               => _x( 'التفاسير', 'post type general name' ),
                'singular_name'      => _x( '', 'post type singular name' ),
                'add_new'            => _x( 'أضف تفسير جديد', 'book' ),
                'add_new_item'       => __( 'أضف تفسير جديد' ),
                'edit_item'          => __( 'تحرير التفسير' ),
                'new_item'           => __( 'تفسير جديد' ),
                'all_items'          => __( 'كافة التفاسير' ),
                'view_item'          => __( 'مشاهدة التفسير' ),
                'search_items'       => __( 'بحث في التفاسير' ),
                'not_found'          => __( 'لا يوجد أي تفسير' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'لا يوجد أي تفسير في سلة المهملات' ), 
                'parent_item_colon'  => '',
                'menu_name'          => 'التفاسير'
            );
            $args = array(
                'labels'        => $labels,
                'description'   => 'يحنوي على معطيات "آية بآية و التفاسير المرفوعة"',
                'public'        => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
                'has_archive'   => true,
                'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'aya-bi-aya'),
            );
            register_post_type( 'aya-bi-aya', $args );  
        }

 add_action( 'init', 'post_type_aya_bi_aya' );

function taxonomy_aya_bi_aya() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'السور', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'السورة', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'بحث في السور' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'كافة السور' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( '' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( '' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'تحرير السورة' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'تحديث السورة' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'أضف سورة' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'سورة جديدة' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'السور' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'public' => TRUE, 
            'show_ui' => TRUE,
                'query_var' => 'sowar',

        );
        register_taxonomy( 'sowar', 'aya-bi-aya', $args );
    }

add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_aya_bi_aya', 0 );
```

I am here to explain more. Good luck.

Comment: So you cannot define the custom fields for the custom posts in functions.php?

Comment: Of course you can in your functions.php. Everything is possible in WP via code. But better use that plugin I tried it and it is making CF mangement easy for default posts and CPTS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the excellent [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

This provides a quick admin interface for creating fields per post type/page template/page type etc and has a very simple API for template use

```
<?php the_field('my_custom_field'); ?>
```

**But the part I think you'll be interested in is you can export your field groups as php and then include them as a part of your theme**